# Prism for XF async OnNavigatedTo returning void an not Task?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

When overriding the Navigation methods like OnNavigatedTo, I get the warning:

```
Asynchronous method 'OnNavigatedTo' should not return void
```

The method is defined as:

`public async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters){}`

Shouldn't this return a Task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not return a Task. You can see the interface definition here:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Forms/Navigation/INavigatedAware.cs

Also, I'm not sure what you mean by overriding. You do not override this method, you implement it via the INavigationAware or INavigatedAware interfaces.